# VB Css background-color of a table within a ListView only paints the visible part of the table

Tags: asp.net, css, listview, header

Hi everyone thx for trying to help.

I have a ListView with a fixed y header. 
The header of my ListView is actually another table formatted to fit the ListView Columns.
I have a JScrollPane and a javascript in order to keep the header fixed at top and to keep it aligned with the ListView columns when I scroll on X Axis.

All fine. Except for the part where i start scrolling from left to right, The header background color is green(as programmed in the css file) only for the visible part of the Table, meaning that as soon as i scroll to the right to see the remaining columns I can notice that the header table isnt colored anymore, its transparent.

[image: before I scroll]

[image: After I scroll]

Here is my css:

```
  .listeResultat
    {
  max-height: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  overflow:hidden ;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #F3F6FA;
    }      


  #parentFixed
 {

       height:800px;
        background-color:#cccccc;
        overflow:auto;
  }

 .headerFixed{

    color:White;
      background-color:green;
    font-size:20px;
       position:static;
     z-index:222;
   }

 .headerFixed table td{
  border: 1px solid #000000 ; 
   min-width: 150px;

  }

  .wrapperfixed{

 height:600px;
 font-size:20px;
 }

/*Celui la ici si on voulais un header fixe vertical aligné a gauche*/
.wrapperfixed .lefter{
 float:left;
width:100px;
height:800px;
background-color:red;
position:relative;
}

.wrapperfixed .content{
 float:left;
 }

 .wrapperfixed .content table td{

 border: 1px solid #000000 ; 
 min-width : 150px;
 }

.wrapperfixed .content table th{

 border: 1px solid #000000 ; 
min-width: 150px;
 }
```

and this is my asp page with the script and everything

```
      <div class="listeResultat">
        <!--début tableau des résultats-->

      <div id="parentFixed">
        <div class="headerFixed">
        <table id="tableHeader">
             <tr>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="Q" runat="server"><%= getCellText("Q")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td> <asp:LinkButton ID="W" runat="server"><%= getCellText("W")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td> <asp:LinkButton ID="E" runat="server"><%= getCellText("E")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td> <asp:LinkButton ID="R" runat="server"><%= getCellText("R")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="T" runat="server"><%= getCellText("T")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="Y" runat="server"><%= getCellText("Y")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="U" runat="server"><%= getCellText("U")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="I" runat="server"><%= getCellText("I")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="O" runat="server"><%= getCellText("O")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="P" runat="server"><%= getCellText("P")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="S" runat="server"><%= getCellText("S")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="L4" runat="server"><%= getCellText("L4")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="L5" runat="server"><%= getCellText("L5")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="A" runat="server"><%= getCellText("A")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="D" runat="server"><%= getCellText("D")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="F" runat="server"><%= getCellText("F")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="G" runat="server"><%= getCellText("G")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="H" runat="server"><%= getCellText("H")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="J" runat="server"><%= getCellText("J")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td> <asp:LinkButton ID="K" runat="server"><%= getCellText("K")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="L" runat="server"><%= getCellText("L")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td> <asp:LinkButton ID="Z" runat="server"><%= getCellText("Z")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td> <asp:LinkButton ID="X" runat="server"><%= getCellText("X")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td> <asp:LinkButton ID="C" runat="server"><%= getCellText("C")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="V" runat="server"><%= getCellText("V")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="B" runat="server"><%= getCellText("B")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="N" runat="server"><%= getCellText("N")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="M" runat="server"><%= getCellText("M")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="QQ" runat="server"><%= getCellText("QQ")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="QW" runat="server"><%= getCellText("QW")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="QL" runat="server"><%= getCellText("QL")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="QE" runat="server"><%= getCellText("QE")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="QR" runat="server"><%= getCellText("QR")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="QT" runat="server"><%= getCellText("QT")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="QY" runat="server"><%= getCellText("QY")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="QU" runat="server"><%= getCellText("QU")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="COM" runat="server"><%= getCellText("COM")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
        </div><%--FIN HEADER FIXED--%>
   <%--Wrapper FIXED--%>
<div class="wrapperfixed">
<div class="content"><%--Content FIXED--%>

<table>

         <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" EnableEventValidation="true">

            <ItemTemplate>

                <tr style="background-color: <%# BgColor(Eval("A"))%>">
                    <td  width="106px">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB1"><a href="Desk.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Q")%>"><%# Eval("Q")%></a></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td  width="106px">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB2"><a href="Desk.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Q")%>"><%# Eval("W")%></A></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td  width="106px">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB3"><%# Eval("E")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td  width="106px">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB4"><%# Eval("R")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td  width="106px">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB5"><%# Eval("T")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td  width="106px">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB6"><%# Eval("Y")%></asp:Label></td>
                     <td  width="106px">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB7"><%# Eval("U")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB8"><%# Eval("I")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB9"><%# Eval("O")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB10"><%# Eval("P")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB12"><%# Eval("S")%></asp:Label></td>
                     <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label4"><%# Eval("L4")%></asp:Label></td>
                     <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label5"><%# Eval("L5")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB11"><a href="Reservation.aspx?<%# getLink(Eval("A"), Eval("Q") , Eval("F"))%>"><%# Eval("A")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB13"><%# Eval("D")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB14"><%# Eval("F")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB15"><%# Eval("G")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB16"><%# Eval("H")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB17"><%# Eval("J")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB18"><%# Eval("K")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB19"><%# Eval("L")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB20"><%# Eval("Z")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB21"><%# Eval("X")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB22"><%# Eval("C")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB23"><%# Eval("V")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB24"><a href="Employee.aspx?id=<%# Eval("L")%>"><%# Eval("B")%></a></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB25"><a href="Employee.aspx?id=<%# Eval("L")%>"><%# Eval("N")%></a></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB26"><%# Eval("M")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB27"><%# Eval("QQ")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB28"><%# Eval("QW")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB29"><%# Eval("QL")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB30"><%# Eval("QE")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB31"><%# Eval("QR")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB32"><%# Eval("QT")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB33"><%# Eval("QY")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB34"><%# Eval("QU")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB35"><%# Eval("COM")%></asp:Label><%--Comments--%>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </ItemTemplate>

            <AlternatingItemTemplate>

                <tr style="background-color: <%# BgColor(Eval("A"))%>">
                    <td  style="width:106px;">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB1"><a href="Desk.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Q")%>"><%# Eval("Q")%></A></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td  style="width:106px;">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB2"><a href="Desk.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Q")%>"><%# Eval("W")%></A></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td  style="width:106px;">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB3"><%# Eval("E")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td  style="width:106px;">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB4"><%# Eval("R")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td  style="width:106px;">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB5"><%# Eval("T")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td  style="width:106px;">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB6"><%# Eval("Y")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td  style="width:106px;">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB7"><%# Eval("U")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB8"><%# Eval("I")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB9"><%# Eval("O")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB10"><%# Eval("P")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <%--<td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"><a href="Reservation.aspx?deskId=<%# Eval("Q")%>"><%# Eval("A")%></a></asp:Label></td>--%>

                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB12"><%# Eval("S")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label6"><%# Eval("L4")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label7"><%# Eval("L5")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                      <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB11"><a href="Reservation.aspx?<%# getLink(Eval("A"), Eval("Q") , Eval("F"))%>"><%# Eval("A")%></a></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB13"><%# Eval("D")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB14"><%# Eval("F")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB15"><%# Eval("G")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB16"><%# Eval("H")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB17"><%# Eval("J")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB18"><%# Eval("K")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB19"><%# Eval("L")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB20"><%# Eval("Z")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB21"><%# Eval("X")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB22"><%# Eval("C")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB23"><%# Eval("V")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB24"><a href="Employee.aspx?id=<%# Eval("L")%>"><%# Eval("B")%></a></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB25"><a href="Employee.aspx?id=<%# Eval("L")%>"><%# Eval("N")%></a></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB26"><%# Eval("M")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB27"><%# Eval("QQ")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB28"><%# Eval("QW")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB29"><%# Eval("QL")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB30"><%# Eval("QE")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB31"><%# Eval("QR")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB32"><%# Eval("QT")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB33"><%# Eval("QY")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB34"><%# Eval("QU")%></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                        <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_LB35"><%# Eval("COM")%>   </asp:Label><%--Comments--%>
                    </td>
                </tr>

             </AlternatingItemTemplate>
         </asp:ListView>

 </table>

</div><%--FIN CONTENT FIXED--%>
 </div><%--FIN WRAPPER FIXED--%>
 <div class="scrollarea"></div><%--Pour activer le javascript du jscrollpane--%>
 </div><%--Fin ParentFixed--%>

<br/><br/>



   <!-- styles pour le jScrollPane -->
  <link type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />

  <!-- jQuery direct de google -->
  <script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

 <!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

 <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>

  <%--Script qui ajoute un event lors de l'utilisation des scrollbar--%>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#parentFixed')
        .bind('jsp-scroll-y',
            function (event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
                $(".headerFixed").css("top", scrollPositionY);
            }
         )
        .bind('jsp-scroll-x',
            function (event, scrollPositionX, isAtLeft, isAtRight) {
                $(".lefter").css("left", scrollPositionX);
            }
    )
    .jScrollPane();
  });
   // alert('I was invoked at the end of the script'); //test pour voir si le scripte   roule
</script>


    </div><%--FIN Div listeResultats--%>
   <%--FIN PANEL DE LA LISTE DES RESULTATS--%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again I found the answer by myself. I have to tell my jquery script that each time the scroll right or left is used to paint the table background

This would be the needed line

```
 $('#tableHeader').css('background-color', '#556d80');
```

This is the whole script

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#parentFixed')
        .bind('jsp-scroll-y',
            function (event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
                $(".headerFixed").css("top", scrollPositionY);
            }
         )
        .bind('jsp-scroll-x',
            function (event, scrollPositionX, isAtLeft, isAtRight) {
                $(".lefter").css("left", scrollPositionX);
                // $('#tableHeader').css('background-color', '#556d80');
                $('#tableHeader').css({ 'background-image':  'url(Styles/grd_head.png)' });
            }
    )
   .jScrollPane();
 });
   // alert('I was invoked at the end of the script'); //TRACE
```